# exchange activesync policy and swipe/pattern locks

Tags: exchange-2010, activesync

Is there a way to allow our Exchange 2010 ActiveSync users to use a swipe or pattern lock? I tried creating the simplest policy possible and testing it on my Android phone, which is now insisting on a PIN or password and doesn't let me choose pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementation of the policy as presented by the server is completely up to the device.

Android's interpretation of that policy seems to be that a pattern lock doesn't fit the policy's demand - your Exchange server really doesn't have any say in the matter.

Aside from rooting phones, your only recourse is probably to file a feature request against Android.

Comment: That, and in Exchange 2010 there is no specific setting to allow pattern vs. PIN.